# Using <rollForward enabled="true" /> in app.config

Tags: c#, .net, clr, app-config

Just curious as to what exactly the rollForward property does when being set in the app.config as follows:

```
<startup>
  <process>
    <rollForward enabled="true" />
  </process>
</startup>
```

I haven't been able to find a whole lot online.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following links clearly explain the use of `rollForward`.

*If you want to force your apps to just use the latest framework that’s available on the machine you can use this relatively undocumented rollForward setting:*

```
<configuration>
...
  <startup>
    <process>
      <rollForward enabled="true" />
    </process>
  </startup>
...
</configuration>
```

*This is of course a great thing if you cannot control what version of the .NET framework and application is being built with (like on a build server) but want to get things running on the latest framework. It’s also a low impact way of testing that large applications continue to work when running on the latest CLR without having to build massive solutions. But you should totally start targeting .NET 4.0 to take advantage of the new framework features.*

1. [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=L6Z3TdQigE0C&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=%3CrollForward%20enabled=%22true%22%20/%3E&source=bl&ots=NarMHBJWGC&sig=aiqCxew8MPMN2vGfvHPKf-BoKz8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9uDNUqY4yuegBOWTgrgB&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%3CrollForward%20enabled=%22true%22%20/%3E&f=false)
2. [Using the new .NET CLR without recompiling](http://brutaldev.com/post/2011/05/03/Using-the-new-NET-CLR-without-recompiling)